# Variable communication from php to javascript both of different pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had a variable in my php page which is an URL printed on that page, I had another html page where I needs this URL value from that php page and it should be assigned to the button in html page.
How can it be performed?

```
 php page content:    
if ($output== true) {
    //Output results as URL
    print_r($resulta);
}
html page content:
<p align="center">
<input type="button" name="res1" value="result">
```

Comment: post what have you tried!!

Comment: use Ajax calls in order to access php variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_GET method to pass variables between PHP pages.
In your PHP page,

```
 <?php
      $value = "Some value"; 
      header("location:nextPage.php?variable=$value");
      exit();
 ?>
```

In the nextPage.php

```
<?php
      $received =  $_GET['variable'];
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title of the document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <<button type="button"><?php  echo $received;  ?></button>
 </body>

 </html>
```

If the next page is not a PHP file, here is a solution,

```
 // THIS WORKS FOR MULTIPLE VALUES, BUT IF YOU DO NOT SEND ANY VALUES, IT WILL SHOW ERROR OF "UNDEFINED". BUT THAT CAN ALSO BE FIXED.
 // EXAMPLE : http://yourdomain.com?tag1=100&tag2=200&tag3=300



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title of the document</title>
 <script>
 var url,url_contents,received_values,passed_values;
 url = document.URL;
 url_contents = url.split("?");
 received_values = url_contents[1];
 received_values = received_values.split("&");
 for(var i=0;i<received_values.length;i++)
 {
 var value_array = received_values[i].split("=");
 alert(value_array[0]+"="+value_array[1]);
 }

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: the nextPage is not a php page. Then, is there any change in code for html page?

Comment: There is no direct way, as far as I know, But you can, using indirect methods. Wait.. I'll compose the script and update the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it. Once you get the values it's not difficult to pass it to the layout elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Ajax.
When you need information to be filled in HTML page the only easy way is Ajax.
I suggest you to use jQuery for simpler requests.

More info about making get request with jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Example:

```js
$(function() {

$.get('request.php', {}, function(response) {
  if (response.url) {
    alert('No information from server!');
    return;
  }
  
  $('button.mybutton').onclick(function() {
    window.location.href = response.url;
  });
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="mybutton">Click</button>
```

And in your PHP something like this:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$response = json_encode(array( 'url' => $url ));
die($response);
```

Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is important when you do an Ajax request from different domains. you can see more usages of it in google: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://www.google.bg/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=am83Va_EJoa4sQHg64GgAQ)